# How to Log Out of Facebook in iOS

Tags: facebook, cocoa-touch

I know how to log in

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:readPermissions allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];//This is done on main thread already
 }];
```

The thing is what to do at logout, say when user press the logout button?

Currently I simply do

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:FACEBOOKSESSIONCHANGED object:self];
```

However, I do not think that's true.     [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]; should be called at [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error]; AFTER logging out.

So what should I do to logout?

I check scrumptuous sample from facebook, I couldn't find their mechanism to logout. It seems that they use specialized facebook viewController that has a delegate. But none of the delegate is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging out mechanism , they just invalidate the access token by releasing it and setting it to nil. But if your login is using safari then still the cookies would exists. So next time if user open safari and try to access Facebook it would say that it is already authorized. 
To delete the cookies I use the following method

```
- (void)fbDidLogout
{
  NSLog(@"Logged out of facebook");
  NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  for (cookie in [storage cookies])
   {
       NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
       NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
       if(domainRange.length > 0)
       {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
       }
   }
}
```

To be more sure you can also call as some bugs are there which return open session even after calling closeAndClearTokenInformation. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/497294866962479?browse=search_507cb8ebc4f025673237228

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[FBSession.activeSession close];
[FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

Other option is to use the following condition while checking for active session .

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
 //logged in
else
 //not logged in
```

Because FBSession.activeSession.state was returning FBSessionStateOpen, not FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded.

Comment: So I am doing the right thing by calling closeAndClearTokenInformation?

Comment: @JimThio You can checkout the implementation of that method to be more sure. But its right :)

Comment: Edited my answer. Call all the three to be sure, crazy bugs. :)

Comment: Interesting... so you call all three methods: closeAndClearTokenInformation, close, and setActiveSession:nil? That trick with the cookies is interesting too since I think we've run into that problem as well, where even when logged out, the Facebook SDK seems to detect the presence of the cookies and maintains the session or seems to re-auth in some fashion. Anyone know if these are still issues in 3.8?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if anyone is still getting bitten by this, but with the latest version of the Facebook SDK, i cannot get an iPad to be forced to log in after logging out. There is still some sort of weirdness here - the 'clear cookies' code is being jumped over - is there a different way to clear cookies in the iPad?
Jerry